# Access a protected field from queried Eloquent object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I query an entity:

```
$trip_redirect_id = Trip::whereUniqueToken($unique_token)->select('id')->get();
```

and try to get the `id` value with `$trip_redirect_id->id` or `$trip_redirect_id['id']` but I get exception that the field is not present.

When I dump the `$trip_redirect_id` object, I can see the `id` and it's value and they are correct (I checked with the database). But how can I access the value inside php?

Comment: There's a getter in there somewhere. Search the class for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, if I use auto-incrementing IDs, I can access the `id` attribute of the newly created model, right after it has been created in the DB.

So, this is the whole fix:

```
$trip->save();

$trip_redirect_id = $trip->id;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using `get()` which is going to be returning a `Collection` of objects so you won't be able to get the attributes of the models unless you iterate through the collection, even if it's just one item in the collection, or just grab the first record.  Use this instead:

```
Trip::whereUniqueToken($unique_token)->select('id')->first();
```